A contradictory statement to prove that the phrase just spoken doesn't make sense, or is impossible: "What? that's like saying ___"
A phrase that would work to show that the previous statement is contradictory. Something that is very clearly a paradox/contradictory. "Vegan bacon" would work if it wasn't a real thing. Not too long.
Also, any example for the previous part of the sentence would be what I am asking for. I don't have the answer yet.

Tell us what comes before "That's like saying..."

"That's like saying a florist doesn't stay open on Mother's Day," which is today in the US. However, there are endless contradictory statements, and we don't do lists here ... no there aren't and yes we do.

Given the lack of detail: a contradictory statement is "That's like saying no."

'Vegan bacon' has doubtless been used figuratively, when it is not incorrect but a concise paradox (oxymoron, now default definition). Used literally, it is a contradiction in terms, nonsense.

Like saying black is white
This is in Cambridge dictionaries which says

If someone says or believes black is white, they say or believe something that is completely untrue, especially because this is helpful to them

Their examples include:

He accused opponents of "running a campaign to say black is white and up is down."

So you have another possibility there. But you could reverse any common saying such as that the grass is blue or the sky is green. There's a fable of a tiger and a donkey where the donkey argues "The grass is blue". I'm not sure what the origin of that tale is though.

Using what is perhaps the most common dissimile in a slightly different way,

It's like saying that chalk is cheese.



Education Minister Bandula Gunawardena appears to be still insisting that his chalk is cheese. [Daily Mirror;
2012]

But to imagine chert is shale or shale is chert is as untenable as claiming that chalk is cheese [Robin
Grayson; Drill or Drop; March 2019]

Joining her in attempting to convince us all that chalk is cheese .... Deirdre Reynolds; Sunday
World; Nov 2023

Of course, if you pull select parts of boat descriptions, you're going to be able to argue that chalk is cheese... . [Mat @ Pyranha, UK
Rivers Guidebook
blog; Mar 2020]

What do you do when someone argues that chalk is cheese? You can only resort to humour, ... [The Free Dictionary Language Forums;
courtesy of
Google]




"What? That's an oxymoron. That's like saying 'old news'."

The default definition of 'oxymoron' is 'a concisely stated paradox', where things do make sense despite at first appearing not to. A 'contradiction in terms' will never make sense.
